# List HTML/CSS design approach

Tags: html, css

I would like to acheive the following using html and css. What would be the best approach to designing the list.

[image]

Comment: Did you try anything? please share your code (HTML/CSS).

Comment: Are you looking for a way to indent every other list item? (if so see Oriol's reply) or how to achieve that exact layout with CSS? (colors, fonts and everything else).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it ([See it live in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Nw99Z/44/](http://jsfiddle.net/Nw99Z/44/) ):

### HTML

```
<div id="box1">
    <span class="num">1</span>
    <h1>We Rule</h1>
    You don't know how much
</div>
<div id="box2">
    <span class="num">2</span>
    <h1>We Super Rule</h1>
    You don't know how much
</div>
<div id="box3">
    <span class="num">3</span>
    <h1>We Are Insanely Awesome</h1>
    You don't even undestand
</div>
<div id="box4">
    <span class="num">4</span>
    <h1>Yes, It's True</h1>
    Yep, it's true
</div>
<div id="box5">
    <span class="num">5</span>
    <h1>I'm Still Talking</h1>
    Yep, I am
</div>

​
```

### CSS

```
body {
    background-color: #0e1013;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
div {
    background-color: #414141;
    color: #ababab;
    padding: 16px 0 16px 100px;
    margin: 16px 0 16px 32px;
}
div span.num {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 56px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
    margin-left: -116px;
    position: absolute;
}
div h1 {
    font-size: 38px;
    color: #fff;
}

div#box1 { width: 370px }
div#box2 { margin-left: 100px; width: 440px }
div#box3 { width: 700px }
div#box4 { margin-left: 160px; width: 460px }
div#box5 { width: 430px }
```

​

### Result

[image: Result screenshot]

Comment: This definitely is **not the best** way of doing it, but it was not clear to me what part exactly was the OP asking about.

Comment: I was thinking the best way to get the styling. Whether using lists, tables or pure css. This is what I was looking for. Thank you. Now, for me to integrate this with bootstrap. I am very new to coding and my colleague is giving me a hard time.

Answer (score 1):

See http://jsfiddle.net/X9Nch/1/

HTML:

```
<ol id="list">
 <li><ul><li>Text 1</li><li>Sub 1</li></ul></li>
 <li><ul><li>Text 2</li><li>Sub 2</li></ul></li>
 <li><ul><li>Text 3</li><li>Sub 3</li></ul></li>
 <li><ul><li>Text 4</li><li>Sub 4</li></ul></li>
 <li><ul><li>Text 5</li><li>Sub 5</li></ul></li>
</ol>
```

CSS:

```
#list{
    background:black;
    color:white;
}
#list>li{
    list-style:decimal inside none;
    font-weight:bold;
    line-height:75px;
    height:75px;
    padding-left:20px;
    font-size:300%;
}
#list>li:nth-child(even){
    padding-left:50px;
}
#list>li>ul{
    font-weight:normal;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:medium;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#list>li>ul>li{
    display:block;
    line-height:normal;
    color:#aaa;
    margin-left:5px;
    padding:0;
}

#list>li>ul>li:first-child{
    font-size:200%;
    color:white;
    margin-left:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should go for nested lists:

```
<ul class="list">
    <li>1
        <ul>
            <li>2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>2</li>
</ul>
```

Then you would use CSS similar to this:

```
/* styles the whole list */
ul.list { }
/* styles 1st level items */
ul.list > li {}

/* styles 2nd level list */
ul.list ul { }

/* styles 2nd level items */
ul.list ul > li { }
```

You can add a `margin-left` to the second level list, or you can specify a default margin for all lists:

```
ul { margin-left:10px }
```

Then all nested lists will inherit the parent's margin, pluss its own, which also would create the layout you specified.

PS: Don't forget to add the rest of the CSS (backgrounds, colors, etc.)..

Edit: An example: http://jsfiddle.net/JTtHY/

Comment: Just because it looks nested in the design doesn't necessarily mean that semantically it _is_ a nested list. In fact I would argue that this is just one ordered list (based on the numbers) and the indentation of every other item is simply a design choice.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I did not consider the numbers being a part of the design, as it looked a bit...strange, and off-placed.